# model to predict variable evolution

Tags: modeling, econometrics, prediction, independence

Suppose that I have a set of variables `X1` `X2` and `X3` that explain the evolution of a dependent variable `Y`. I want to verify empirically if `X1` `X2` and `X3` can predict the future evolution of `Y`.
I am looking for a model that allows to test and compare this predictive capacity.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for a straightforward regression of `Y` on `X1`, `X2` and `X3`. Prediction would be straightforward, by feeding the new values into the design matrix. Or, if you have time series, you may want to look at ARIMAX models, or at regressions with ARIMA errors.

Once you have built your model, you can assess the predictive power of your covariates by predicting a holdout sample with and without them and comparing errors. You can check whether differences in errors are statistically significant by using Diebold-Mariano type tests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am working on time series .. If I understand well, I need to get the errors of X1 X2 X3 and Y using ARIMA, then do an OLS regression to get the predictive coefficients?

Comment: I suggest using R, looking at `auto.arima()` (especially the `xreg` parameter) in the `forecast` package and reading [this blog post by Rob Hyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). A few [earlier posts of mine](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1352+xreg) may also be helpful. Good luck!